# RF sources location system

Tags: rf

At my workplace we have to monitor devices that operate at 433 and 869 MHz, but lately there's an area that for some reason has a transmitter, that isn't ours, jamming the communications. The signal is operating at 869.525 MHz, completely covers a small town and, has far has we know, doesn't seem modular and emits 24/7.

Is it possible to build some kind of circuit capable of getting the distance, signal strength or relative position to find out the origin of this problem?

Comment: It's time for a [fox hunt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmitter_hunting)! You could get a lot of good advice on the [Amateur Radio SE](http://ham.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You haven't mentioned a country but one step you could take first is try to determine if the signal is likely to be legal based on local regulations. If legal there's probably not much you can do about it on a license-free band but if not you could report it to the relevant authority and leave them to track it down.

Comment: The signal is operating on a free band but I think there is a power limit that the signal is not respecting.

Comment: Has for the authority, I live in Portugal, so the best approach is usually to avoid the costly bureaucracy and try to solve the problem directly and peacefully.

Comment: Is the signal modulated (AM/FM/SSB) or continuous? Is the signal 24 hours every day, or only during business hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it could be as follows. You buy a directional antenna (for example a Yagi type) for the intended frequency plus an spectrum analyzer/module/receiver able to tell the RSSI, find an elevated position in your town and from there rotate the antenna until you get a peak in RSSI. So now you know the direction of the transmitter relative to your location. Then you could find another elevated position somewhere else in the town and repeat the procedure. Finally an approximate position of the transmitter can be found on a map by intersecting the two found directions.

About your question of building a receiver yourself, I would really advise against. A low cost solution could be this one: http://www.ti.com/tool/cc1120emk-868-915 . This receiver can be connected to a laptop through CCDebugger (low cost device from TI) and then controlled from SmartRFStudio software which is free.